# Which method is more efficient performance wise for Android SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database consisting of columns:

```
bookId, pageNbr, text
```

where bookId and pageNbr are indexed.

Now, in using it as a data model for my list view, should I initialize a cursor using:

```
SELECT bookId, pageNbr, text
FROM table
WHERE bookId BETWEEN 1 AND 5
AND pageNbr BETWEEN 100 AND 500
```

Or should I get each item for each row, each time getView is called using this:

```
SELECT bookId, pageNbr, text
FROM table
WHERE bookId = VAR_BOOK_ID
AND pageNbr = VAR_PAGE_NBR
```

Is there any performance difference? (perhaps overhead if any for each query?)

Comment: Of course there's a performance overhead fetching one item versus potentially over a thousand

Comment: But how about compared to much larger query as the first?

Comment: That's what I'm saying - the first way is less optimal, but at least you only hit the database once.

Comment: Use lazy loading,fetch sql record whenever user scroll down a list

Comment: I'm confused about your comments. Should I use the first or the second? I'm actually using the first since I think it's better to fetch once.

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya Isn't it the second you're talking about?

Comment: @SidGo yes use second method but with care,you should call it only when your row layout for each item is created first time i.e. when convertView is null.Also learn about lazy loading,its not as straight forward as you are thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever query is easier to handle (i.e., the first one). This results in the most efficient development performance.

Think about optimizing only when you *measure* an actual problem.

As for the queries: only one BETWEEN can be optimized with an index, so you need to index only the column that has greater selectivity.
And doing two lookups with `=` works best if there is a two-column index.

Comment: Can you tell me in simple terms what is selectivity? Is it the column that has the greatest number of possible values that has the greatest selectivity?

Comment: The column where the comparison filters out the most rows (so that as few rows as possible need to be read from the actual table).